# Is this a legitimate XSS vulnerability and if yes, how to refactor to fix it?

Tags: javascript, xss

The following function is flagged as a reflective vector for XSS attacks by scanning software. However, the function is never passed any user-inputted data of any kind nor does it use data from a database that has user-entered data.

Added: The goal of the code is a simple module for other classes to call and build a button with an assigned event action.

So,

1. this cannot be a vector for XSS attacks, correct?
2. if I missed something in my understanding of XSS vulnerabilities even when no user-entered data is used, how should this be re-factored to eliminate the threat?

```
export default class Button {
    constructor(html = "", classList = []) {

        this._button = document.createElement("button");
        this._button.classList.add(...classList);
        this._button.innerHTML = html; // <-- flagged by scanning software
    }
    
    get button() {
        return this._button;
    }
    
    setOnClickAction(action = null) {
        if (action === null || !(action instanceof Function)) {
            throw new Error("Button action cannot be null.");
        }

        this._element.addEventListener("click", action);
    }
}
```

function is called like this:

```
const button = new Button("General<small><br>(Receiving)</small>",
                                  ["btn", "btn-light", "btn-outline-dark", "ml-1", "mr-1", "text-info"]);
```

Comment: Where does `html` come from?

Comment: its an issue if you do pass user-submitted data to it, does your *scanner* test injection or is it just seeing innerHTML?

Comment: @ jabaa html is from other code modules that need buttons. This function is used to encapsulate a simple button. The other modules also do not accept user-input of any kind.

Comment: @Lawrence Scanner is run by corporate Cyber team and I do not know details. I do know that people who run the scanner know nothing of coding and do not understand the code context. However, I am at best beginner to intermediate JS developer and want to understand this potential issue better.

Comment: Even if this isn't a security issue right now, it's worth dealing with so no one shoots themselves in the foot with it later. Why would you need to allow that much control (passing HTML in) of a buttons content? Surely a string and a few pre-defined options would cover 99% of buttons?

Comment: @DBS The intent is to encapsulate button creation since I used that code in dozens of places and just refactored it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure no user created values at all are entered in the `html` argument, then it is fine.

On another note, you shouldn't be using `.innerHTML` unless the value will pass in HTML like `<h1>content here</h1>`. Instead, use `.innerText`, which does not allow HTML to be rendered, instead passes plain `CDATA` content.

Comment: The input is always actual HTML that is generated by other classes. None of the HTML has any user-inputted data at all. In fact, the entire app is read only but our corporate software flags and say I have to fix it. Not sure what to fix, though.

Comment: @JJJulien Then you should be fine. Try to check your scanning software's documentation to see if there is a way to disable it for the line.

Comment: The reason it is flagged by the scan tool is because it just finds patterns, and is not very smart. However, the reason you should not just ignore this ("disable for the line") is because maybe now it never has user input. Then somebody else after a few years adds a completely new section to the app. Then when neither you nor this new dev even work there anymore, a third guy creates a new button that says "Delete". Then a product manager says ok but it should be more clear what we are deleting, let's show the title. So a fourth dev adds the user-set title to the button. Who will discover XSS?